# javascript form action changesrc method post text input onsubmit

Tags: javascript, html, forms

i'm just trying to post a form's text input into an iframe with a return, no submit button.

```
function changesrc(main, url) {
document.getElementById('main').setAttribute('src', url);
}
```

my main iframe

```
<div id="frame"><iframe id="main" name="main" type="text/html" src="" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

the actual text input parent form is what is throwing me off...

```
<form id="url" onSubmit='changesrc('main', target)' method="post"><div id=target><input type="text" name="target" id="target" size="65"></div></form>
```

pls no implications or degradations, i know this code is lousy...

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of obvious problems with the code you posted:

```
function changesrc(main, url) {
    document.getElementById('main').setAttribute('src', url);
}
```

Also, to access the `src` of the `main` element, simply use dot-notation, which results in the following:

```
function changesrc(main, url) {
    document.getElementById(main).src = url;
}
```

In the above function you should either use the argument supplied to the function as the string in the `document.getElementById()` *or* the string (as you currently are), but if you're passing the argument you should probably use it (otherwise there's no point).

```
<form id="url" action='changesrc('main', target)' method="post">
    <div id=target>
        <input type="text" name="target" id="target" size="65"></div>
    </form>
</div>
```

In this you've tried to quote the string within the string using the same string-delimiters. To get around that problem you should use single-quotes within a double-quote delimited string:

```
<form id="url" action="changesrc('main', target)" method="post">
```

Or double-quotes wtihin a single-quote delimited string:

```
<form id="url" action='changesrc("main", target)' method="post">
```

The `action` attribute is used to specify to where the form data should be submitted, such as a server-side script; not for client-side event-handling; if you must use in-line event handling, you should use the `onkeypress` event-handler:

```
<form id="url" onkeypress="changesrc('main', target)" method="post">
```

Comment: noticed the "delimiters" as you call them, and found onsubmit, note to have http:// also when submitting the form to function; thanks for the clear interpretation, and quick response

Answer (score 0):

Check your code:

In

```
<form id="url" action='changesrc('main', target)' method="post"><div id=target><input type="text" name="target" id="target" size="65"></div></form>
```

you have `action='changesrc('main', target)'`. It should be `action="changesrc('main', target)"`, because attributes should be double quoted and, if you want them single quoted, you should escape the other single quotes.

But `target` attribute is the file to which you want to send the form. You want to execute `changesrc` when the form is being submited, so it's `onsubmit="changesrc('main',target)"`.

But then we have `onsubmit="changesrc('main', target)"`. But instead of the undefined variable `target`, you want the value of the input with `id="target"`. Then, it's `onsubmit="changesrc('main', document.getElementById('target').value)"`. But after calling that function, I guess you don't want to send the form to the server, so we need `onsubmit="changesrc('main',document.getElementById('target').value);return false;"`

But then the problem is that you have two elements with `id="target"`. So remove it from the `<div>`.

Then, you have

```
function changesrc(main, url) {
    document.getElementById('main').setAttribute('src', url);
}
```

well, it works, but you aren't using the parameter `main`. I guess you want

```
function changesrc(main, url) {
    document.getElementById(main).setAttribute('src', url);
}
```

The final code is:

HTML:

```
<form id="url" onsubmit="changesrc('main',document.getElementById('target').value);return false;" method="post">
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="target" id="target" size="65">
    </div>
</form>

<div id="frame">
    <iframe id="main" name="main" type="text/html" src="" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function changesrc(main, url) {
    document.getElementById(main).setAttribute('src', url);
}
```

You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/UsGJb/

Comment: yeah, i saw the same target id's, and i believe i understand delimiters, values, and passing forms to functions; thank you for the live example